# difference between select * and count(*)

Tags: mysql

i am newbie in php and mysql !

i have question , whats difference between select * and count(*) ?

for example whats meaning of     `SELECT * FROM tablename` and whats meaning of `SELECT count(*) FROM tablename`
and what difference of them ?

`SELECT * FROM tablename`

`SELECT count(*) FROM tablename`

Comment: Open a mysql console and try it yourself.

Comment: Question shows no effort to research the problem

Answer (score 2):

One counts `count(*)` the number of rows. The other grabs the values for those rows

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a table that holds data about your 50 employees

- each row being a separate employee. `Select *` would return the entire table,

  whereas `Select Count(*)` would return the number of rows - which is 50.

Comment: Can someone suggest the performance consideration of both. Assuming that i wanted to get only the count

Which is better ?
$result = 'select * from user'
count( $result)

or 

$count = select count(*) from user

Answer (score 1):

SELECT* will return all results in a table, and their content/value. Count(*) returns the number of entries in the table.

Answer (score 0):

`Select *` Would return the entire table while `Select Count(*)` would return the number of rows.